# How to save intent key-value data and restore it in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I am new to android studio Kotlin.

I want to make a quiz app with multiple levels. When the level button in the LevelActivity is pressed, the key-value pair is passed to ProblemActivity using intent.putExtra("problem1", 1) and the ProblemActivity shows a problem using intent.hasExtra("problem", 1). If I get the problem right, come back to the LevelActivity with intent.putExtra("Clear1", 101) and the next level button is clickable by intent.hasExtra("Clear1").

I want to make the buttons that were clickable with the previous data remain clickable when I close the app and run it again. I studied SharedPreference, but I am not sure how to save and restore intent data because most of the content is about edit_text. I would appreciate it if you let me know.

Thank you.

LevelActivity.kt

class LevelActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level)


    if (intent.hasExtra("Clear1")) {
        easy2.isEnabled = true
        easy2.isClickable = true
        easy2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
    } else {
        easy2.isEnabled = false
        easy2.isClickable = false
    }

    easy1.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, ProblemActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("problem1", 1)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
        finish()
    }
    easy2.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, ProblemActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("problem2", 2)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2)
        finish()
    }
}
```

}

ProblmeActivity.kt

var round = 1

class ProblemActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_problem)

    if (intent.hasExtra("problem1")) {
        img_problem.setImageResource(R.drawable.slide1)
        tv_problem.text = "Plus"
        tv_problemlevel.text = "1"
        round = 1
    }

    if (intent.hasExtra("problem2")) {
        img_problem.setImageResource(R.drawable.slide2)
        tv_problem.text = "Minus"
        tv_problemlevel.text = "2"
        round = 2
    }

    tv_enter.setOnClickListener {
        checkAnswer()
    }

fun checkAnswer() {

    if (tv_expression.text.toString() == "1" && round == 1) {
        val intent = Intent(this, LevelActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Clear1", "Clear1")
        startActivityForResult(intent, 101)
        finish()
    }
    if (tv_expression.text.toString() == "2" && round == 2) {
        val intent = Intent(this, LevelActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Clear2", 102)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 102)
        finish()
    }
    else{
        var wrong_toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong! Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        wrong_toast.show()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use sharedpreferences and get values from it when the app opens.
I do not think there is another way unless you use sqlite